# Ggplot bar chart: how to show precentage on the y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm very new to R and trying to create some meaningful bar charts with my data. Here is some example code for a simple bar chart using `ggplot2`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

#a variable with 4 different levels
category <- as.factor(c(1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 4, 4, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1))
#a variable with either 0 ("false") or 1 ("true")
quality <- as.factor(c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1))
mydata <- data.frame(category, quality)

plot1 <- ggplot(mydata, aes(x= category, fill=quality)) +
  geom_bar(width=0.25) +
  ggtitle("example") +
  xlab("category") +
  ylab("count") +
  labs("true")
plot1
```

So far I only know how to create a bar chart with counts (n) on the y-axis, with the bar filled based on the number of instances that are `true`. However, I need the **precentage** of instances that are `true` in each category. For example: there are 4 instances belonging to category 1, 3 of which are labeled as `true`. I need the y-axis to show the precentage which in the case of category 1 would be 75,0%. For category 2 that would be `2/7 * 100 = 28,6%`.

Hope this explanation makes sense and someone can suggest a solution! Thank you in advance.

### Edit

I have refined my code a bit but now I'm facing a new problem. It feels like the answer should be obvious but I can't figure this out:

```
category <- as.factor(c(1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 4, 4, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1))
quality <- as.factor(c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1))
mydata <- data.frame(category, quality)

mydata<- mydata %>% group_by(category,quality) %>% mutate(count_q = n()) %>% ungroup() %>%
  group_by(category) %>% mutate(tot_q=n(),pc=count_q*100/tot_q)  %>% unique() %>% arrange(category)

plot1 <- ggplot(mydata, aes(x= category, y = pc)) +
  geom_bar(position = 'dodge', stat='identity', fill="red") +
  geom_text(aes(label=round(tot_q)), position=position_dodge(0.9), vjust=-0.5) +
  ggtitle("example") +
  xlab("category") +
  ylab("count")
plot1
```

For some reason this gives me the tot_q values twice on top of the bar chart. So how to remove the extra values?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is one approach using `dplyr`

> setup `library` and generate data

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#a variable with 4 different levels
category <- as.factor(c(1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 4, 4, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1))
#a variable with either 0 ("false") or 1 ("true")
quality <- as.factor(c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1))
mydata <- data.frame(category, quality)
#
```

> Calculate `pc` percent variable using `dplyr`

```
mydata<- mydata %>% group_by(category,quality) %>% mutate(count_q = n()) %>% ungroup() %>%
  group_by(category) %>% mutate(tot_q=n(),pc=count_q*100/tot_q)  %>% unique() %>% arrange(category)
```

> Generate plot, one correction change `y = quality` to `y = count_q`

```
plot1 <- ggplot(mydata, aes(x= category, y = count_q, fill=quality)) +
  geom_bar(position = 'dodge', stat='identity') +
  geom_text(aes(label=round(pc,digits=1)), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25) +
  ggtitle("example") +
  xlab("category") +
  ylab("count") +
  labs("true")
plot1
```

[image: Output plot]

Comment: Thank you! In your example the precentages are showing which is fantastic. However, is it possible to get a precentage scale for the y axis (from 0% to 100%), so that I could have a visual representation of the percent values? That way I could see from the graphic itself which category has the largest proportion of the "true" quality.

Comment: @Mari I have updated the code a bit. Does this address your question?

Comment: Yes, much better. Thanks! Now just for some fine tuning: how might I hide the precentage for quality 0/false and only show the bars for quality 1/true?

Comment: @Mari that’s great can you share your solution ? Thanks !

Comment: I removed ```fill=quality``` from the code entirely

Comment: I also changed ```y=count_q``` to ```y=pc``` so that the height of the bars are proportionate to each other. Now it does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

@sachin2014 showed a great example of pre-processing the data. But we can also use the special variables in `ggplot2` to do the same thing.

We can use `tapply` to get the `sum` of the `..count..`s of each `..x..`. `..x..` is each category since we defined it in the main `aes()`.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mydata, aes(x= category, fill=quality)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = ..count..),width=0.75, position = "dodge") +
  geom_text(stat="count", aes(label = round((..count../tapply(..count.., ..x.. ,sum)[..x..])*100,1)),
            position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25) +
  ggtitle("example") +   xlab("category") +  ylab("count") + labs("true")
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of `label = round((..count../tapply(..count.., ..x.. ,sum)[..x..])*100,1)` you could use `label = scales::percent(..count../tapply(..count.., ..x.. ,sum)[..x..], accuracy=0.01)`.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this one as well and see what works best with my data.